# How do variable functions in PHP work?

Tags: php, function

In php.net the following is written:

> Variable functions won't work with language constructs such as echo, print, unset(), isset(), empty(), include, require and the like. Utilize wrapper functions to make use of any of these constructs as variable functions.

[source](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php)

What does that mean?
Could anyone give examples because I’ve tried using the variable function in an echo and it worked perfectly:

```
function city()
{
    return "new york";
}
$var = "city";
echo "city:  "  . $var();
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It means you can’t do something like this:

```
$var = "echo";
$var "Hello World!";
```

Comment: `+1` Ding ding ding! :-D

Comment: The comment about wrapper functions means you /can/ do something like this: 
`function myecho($str) { echo $str; } $var = "myecho"; $var("Hello world!");`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that with these functionns echo, print, unset(), isset(), empty() because actualy in php they are not functions, they are reserved keywords with functions call like.

Answer (score -1):

Correct Way is

```
function city()
{
    return "new york";
}
$var = "city";
echo "city:  "  . city();
```

It will Return :

city: new york

Comment: This answer is not helpful and you've completed negated the purpose in setting `$var`.